# spark scala filter using placeholder syntax

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have following source file

```
id,name,year,rating,duration

 1. The Nightmare Before Christmas,1993,3.9,4568
 2. The Mummy,1932,3.5,4388
 3. Orphans of the Storm,1921,3.2,9062
 4. The Object of Beauty,1991,2.8,6150
 5. Night Tide,1963,2.8,5126
 6. One Magic Christmas,1985,3.8,5333
```

I am trying to `filter` all rows where `year=2012` and the following works.

```
c.map(_.split(",")).filter(x=>x(2).toInt==2012)
```

But how can I achieve the same using `placeholder` syntax (`_`) ???

I could use `placeholder` syntax (`_`) in `map` function (e.g. `rdd.map((_.split(","))  )`

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for

```
c.map(_.split(",")).filter(_(2).toInt==2012)
```

But I suggest you to use Spark-CSV to read a csv file like

```
val df1 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", true)
              .option("header",true)
              .option("delimiter", ",")
              .csv("data1.csv")
```

and then you can filter easily as

```
df1.filter($"year" === "2012")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Instead of 
val df1 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", true)
              .option("header",true)
              .option("delimiter", ",")
              .csv("data1.csv")
will it be:
val df1 = sqlContext.read.option("inferSchema", true)
              .option("header",true)
              .option("delimiter", ",")
              .csv("data1.csv")

Please let me know.

Comment: I have to check.

Comment: Meanwhile can you please help me with the following error:

Comment: yeah sure, but with what?

Comment: scala> val df1 = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", true).option("header",true).option("delimiter", ",").csv("/user/mailtosudiptabiswa
s7917/src_files/movies_data_srcfile_sess06_01.csv")


<console>:21: error: not found: value spark
       val df1 = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", true).option("header",true).option("delimiter", ",").csv("/user/mailtosudiptabiswa
s7917/src_files/movies_data_srcfile_sess06_01.csv")

Please help with all the commands required, like any import

Comment: For that you just need
 val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder by simply doing the following

```
c.map(_.split(",")).filter(_(2).toInt==2012).map(_.toSeq).foreach(println)
```

But I would suggest you to go with case class if you know your data is of fixed length

```
case class row(id: String,
             name: String,
             year: String,
             rating: String,
             duration: String)
```

and you can use it as

```
    c.map(_.split(",", -1)).map(array => row(array(0),array(1),array(2),array(3),array(4))).filter(x => x.year.toInt == 2012).foreach(println)
```

Or to be on the safe side you can combine `Option` as

```
c.map(_.split(",", -1)).map(array => {
  row(Option(array(0)) getOrElse "",
    Option(array(1)) getOrElse "",
    Option(array(2)) getOrElse "",
    Option(array(3)) getOrElse "",
    Option(array(4)) getOrElse "")
  })
  .filter(x => x.year.toInt == 2012)
  .foreach(println)
```

Comment: throwing: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

since there are lines like: 12991,Jericho,2006,4.1, (where the fourth position after the 3rd comma is empty).

Comment: If you have comma at the end and are last value or ending values are all empty then you can use `-1` in split to include all of the data as `.split(",", -1)`. with addition to that you can use `Option` for safety.

Comment: Updated my answer. :)

Comment: I just checked only with "map(_.split(",", -1))" without the "case class row(....)".  
<br/> map(_.split(",", -1)) does not seem to work if a field is null

Comment: id,name,year,rating,duration 
1,The Nightmare Before Christmas,1993,3.9,4568
2,The Mummy,1932,3.5,4388
3,Orphans of the Storm,1921,3.2,9062
4,The Object of Beauty,1991,2.8,6150
12991,Jericho,2006,4.1,
5,Movie_1,1991,2.8,6150
6,Movie_2,,2.8,6150

Comment: The last record has null in 'year' field

Comment: val a = sc.textFile("/user/mailtosudiptabiswas7917/src_files/file1.csv")

a.count()

val b = a.first()

val c=a.filter(record=>record!=b)

c.map(_.split(",", -1)).filter(x=>x(2).toInt==2012).count()

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 6, loca
lhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: As you can see still I am getting error even when I am using map(_.split(",", -1)). Please help

Comment: are your data on the same line or separate lines?  If they are on separate lines then are you sure of the data you commented above?